# ConstraintCollectors not recognized in Spring Boot (STS)

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I'm trying to make use of the Optaplanner constraintprovider, which works fine until I want to use the `count()` ConstraintCollector.

I try to use it in a `groupBy`-clause, but I get the error: `The method count() is undefined for the type hamxConstraintProvider`
I was under the assumption this should "just work"? Or should I write my own method for count? I couldn't find that happening in the examples, but seem unable to fix it either. Am I overlooking an import?

```
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.Constraint;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintFactory;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintProvider;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.uni.UniConstraintCollector;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.bi.BiConstraintCollector;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintCollectors.*;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.Joiners.*;

...

public class hamxConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider{


    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
                skillUnavailable(constraintFactory),
                balancedJobs(constraintFactory)
        };
    }


...

    private Constraint balancedJobs(ConstraintFactory factory) {

        return factory.from(Job.class)
                .groupBy(Job::getEmployee,count())
                .penalize("unbalancedEmployeeUsage", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,count);
    }
```

Comment: Which version of OptaPlanner are you using? Does it compile?

Comment: To balance the jobs, you 'll have to penalize `count * count` (so count²), see docs section "fairness". Just using `count` will have zero impact.

Comment: It does not compile, the STS ide signals it as an error immediately. I'm on Optaplanner 7.30.0.Final

Comment: Thanks for the count² hint, didn't get that far yet, but saved me a headache :-)

Comment: Does it compile with Maven or Gradle? Try using `ConstraintCollectors.count()` instead of just `count()`. Set your IDE language level to Java 8 or higher.

Comment: Adding ```ConstraintCollectors.```did the trick, however the ```count*count``` is still marked as an error (```Could not be resolved to a variable```) and however the program runs without crashing on it; the score is not influenced. Or so it seems... Java at 11 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintCollectors.*;
import org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.Joiners.*;
```

use *static* imports:

```
import static org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.ConstraintCollectors.*;
import static org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.Joiners.*;
```

The former imports classes, the latter imports static methods.

Comment: Whoa thanks! That helped a lot: did not know of static imports! Fixes part 1 (count()) but the count*count remains an issue. Did I miss something and do I have to declare & assign the count someplace?

Comment: Oddly enough it compiles, however there is no influence on the score

Comment: Probably empty lists on the planning solution or missing ProblemFactCollectionProperty annotations

Answer (score 0):

`count()` and `countLong()` are methods of ConstraintCollectors. If it compiles but doesn't run, you're likely not providing Spring's ClassLoader to the SolverConfig.

In the next release, 7.32, we're releasing optaplanner-spring-boot-starter, which will make Spring Boot integration a lot easier (it just auto injects a `SolverManager` (or `SolverFactory`, but the former is the latter on steriods)